# Toggle image source with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to do something interesting, so for example i have an image on my website and i want to change it when a button is triggered, but then i want to revert it back to the original when the button is clicked again (or add the same img to it) and repeat this all the time when the event is clicked. How can I achieve this ?

Here is my current Jquery but only that works for one time click

```
    $('#menu-btn').on({
        'click': function () {
            $('#div1').attr('src', 'images/card-light.png');
        }
    });
```

Html code

```
<button id="menu-btn">click me</button>
<img id="div1" src="./images/card-dark.png">
```

Assets

```
images/card-dark.png
images/card-light.png
```

Comment: So you need to toggle images when the same button is clicking again and again right?

Comment: Can you put both image paths in data attributes on the image element?

Comment: giving an image tag an id "div1" is a bad idea already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On document load, store the image source in a variable. In our case, it's called `prev`.

Inside the toggle function, we check whether the source of the image is equal to the source when it was loaded. If it was, we change the source to another image. When the source is changed and we call the `toggle` function again, we know that the source is different from the previous one, so we revert it back to the original source.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#img');
  var prev = img[0].src;
  function toggle(img) {
    let src = img.src;
    if (src == prev) {
      img.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/453956388851445761/8BKnRUXg_400x400.png";
      img.height="48";
    } else {
      img.src = prev;
    }
  }
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    toggle(img[0]);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" height="48"></script>
<img id="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
<button>Toggle</button>
```

We can take it a step further by using data attributes to store the two sources so you can easily extend this for multiple images.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#img');
  var prev = img[0].src;
  function toggle(i) {
    let src = i[0].src;
    let dsrc = i.data('switch-with');
    if(dsrc==src){
      i[0].src=prev;
    }else{
      i[0].src=dsrc;
      i[0].height="48";
    }
  }
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    toggle(img);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" height="48"></script>
<img id="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" data-switch-with="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/453956388851445761/8BKnRUXg_400x400.png">
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Can you please simplify it, why you're using other variables than mine also why 3 images instead of 2? btw Thank you, also notice that im using local images not url

Comment: thank you, also you;re using img element, can you change it to id because i'm using multipe images

Comment: is working good, thank you, I wish i could accept the anwser but i can't becuase my reputation is low, I will do it when i get those points i need to approve it.

Comment: @asdas12 No problem. Glad to help :)